# Conda build: github and bitbucket

Tags: github, bitbucket, conda, conda-build

I'm making a conda package for a toolkit that was published on bitbucket. Looking through the documentation for the meta.yml file, specifically the source section, the possibilities are git_url and hg_url. The url given is .git, but not from github. Does this make any difference? Also, where do I then find the git_rev string?

Thank you!

`source:
  git_url: https://bitbucket.org/***/***.git
  git_rev: master`

edit: Added code in markdown format, removed attempted code pasting in comments.

Comment: This question will be clearer if you post a short snippet of your `meta.yml` showing the referenced configuration :)

Comment: Better if you add it to the question with Markdown code formatting!

Comment: Thanks @PaulBenn, I was trying to use the markdown format here and failing miserably...

Answer (score 1):

The git_url works so long as it is a .git link, not only if it is a github link. For git_rev on bitbucket, it is the branch that will be pulled from.